# Encrypting a string in PHP vs NodeJS

Tags: php, node.js, encryption

I'm trying to encrypt (create a hash) of a string in PHP and duplicate the behaviour in NodeJS. I'm not worried about security on the strings. Both strings should match.

This is the PHP code that I have:

```
$key = 'supersecretkey';

$plaintext = "example string to encrypt";
$cipher = "rc4-hmac-md5";

$encryptedText = openssl_encrypt($plaintext, $cipher, $key);

echo $encryptedText . "\n";
```

This is my output

```
> php crypto.php
cRRDH1KSTZmbWLx+h0Q/l17jfDeAsQb/GA==
```

This is the NodeJS that I have tried:

```
var crypto = require('crypto'),
  algorithm = 'rc4-hmac-md5',
  password = 'supersecretkey';

function encrypt(text){
  var cipher = crypto.createCipher(algorithm,password)
  var crypted = cipher.update(text,'utf8','hex')
  crypted += cipher.final('hex');
  return crypted;
}

var hw = encrypt("example string to encrypt")
// outputs hello world
console.log(hw);
```

And this is the output:

```
> node crypto.js
7ddd856a0227489b5cabda26e82eb99fb0c2ec9b6dfb477d43
```

Why are these values different and how do I get them the same?

Answer (score 0):

While I'm unfamiliar with both of these specific APIs, I do notice you are using a an initialization vector with openssl, but not with node.js.  I would try using the Node.js `crypto.createCiperhiv` form (https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipheriv_algorithm_key_iv_options) and be sure to use the same exact initialization vector bytes for both php and node.js (you should be able to just create some arbitrary ascii string, e.g. "my initialization vector", of the appropriate size).

(an initialization vector is another configuration input to a crypytographic cipher that acts as a seed that introduces additional randomness/variability)

Comment: I removed the initialization vector from the PHP code as it actually doesn't do anything for that cipher algorithm. I've edited the OP and attached the result (which is the same string).